# Attributive nouns: 'trade' and 'trading' with a noun

Tags: modifiers, attributive-nouns

I am a bit confused when it comes to attributive nouns, i.e. when nouns serve as adjectives. The greatest problem for me is whether I need to use attributive nouns as they are or in their -ing form. For instance, is it *'trading contacts'* or *'trade contacts'*?

Is there any rule that could guide me here?

Comment: Much the same choice arises with ***work / working practices, garden / gardening tools, golf / golfing shoes,...*** Offhand I can't think of any such pair that are generally understood to have *different* meanings, and I can't say what if any rule / principle might explain any such difference. Mostly, the two forms will be equivalent, but one will be more common than the other. In your case, ***trade contracts*** is far more common, but I can't see any good reason why that should *happen* to be the case.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of a general rule.

Most of the time, I would opt for the noun. But there are distinctions to be drawn. A **trade contact** (someone involved in trade) might not mean the same thing as a **trading contact** (someone on the trading floor of an exchange).

Similarly, there is a difference between **sports contacts** (those involved in sports administration) and **sporting contacts** (those who play sport).

Such distinctions are likely to apply in many instances. I think that it depends on the word and the context.

Comment: I misread OP's ***contracts*** as ***contracts***, but regardless of that I don't recognise the distinction you make here (between trade/trading and sports/sporting both modifying "contact").

Comment: @FumbleFingers How about the distinctions between sleep / cloth specialists and sleeping / clothing specialists? Between **drink contacts** and **drinking contacts**, between **bed manufacturers** and **bedding manufacturers**?

Comment: There's a huge difference between "sleep" and "sleeping" in most contexts - but although we have the highly idiomatic "sleeping partners", I don't recognise "sleep / sleeping contacts" as meaningful collocations. And there's an even bigger difference between "cloth" and "clothing" (but neither of "cloth / clothing contacts" makes much sense to me either). Finally, no-one would dispute that a "bed" (the actual item of "furniture") is completely different to "bedding" (sheets, pillows, duvets,...).